# How to disable ckeckbox without input type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I disable input type checkbox by adding a disabled.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1_2" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber " name="code[]" placeholder="2" disabled >
```

How to disable a checkbox without input type?

```
<div id="1_2" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber " name="code[]"  disable>2</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean?..

Comment: It won't be a checkbox then if it's not having a `type`, you can make it `read only`

Comment: Your DIV isn't a checkbox, it can't be disabled. You probably have a framework that converts the DIV to a checkbox

Comment: Your second example does not consist of a `checkbox` but rather of a `div`, not an input-element. It is unclear what do you want to achieve since the `div` does not handle any input and can't thus be `disabled`. If you need to just style a `div` as a disabled checkbox then you probably need to add another `class` to it, e.g. `seatNumber __disabled` and program CSS as appropriate.

Comment: I think he is using Mozilla ARIA checkbox rule..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_checkbox_role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The **disabled** property won't work on `div`

**First Solution**

You have to do it through css `Pointer-events` and make it `selection` to none.

Check the below **snippet**

```css
.disabled{
 pointer-events: none;
 opacity: 0.4;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none;   
  -khtml-user-select: none;    
  -moz-user-select: none;      
  -ms-user-select: none;     
  user-select: none; 
}
```

```html
<div id="1_2" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatNumber disabled" name="code[]" readonly="true">Disabled div</div>
```

**Second Solution**

You can also achieve this by using `pseudo` elements to make it look like disabled. Using the below `css`.

**Second Snippet**

```css
.disabled{
   position:relative;
   display:inline-block;
}
.disabled:before{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #000;
   content: '';
   opacity: 0.001;
}
```

```html
<div id="1_2" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatNumber disabled" name="code[]" readonly="true">Disabled div</div>
```

Comment: just for the record `pointer-events` and `user-select` have a support of IE 11+

Comment: @eltonkamami i know, Thanks but there won't be any other solution to disable a `div`, if there is share with us. :)

Comment: nice. i see you found another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Well, that div is not a real checkbox so it does not support `disable` attribute. You have to implement it yourself:

- In your JS: remove or disable whatever event handlers you have for that checkbox and add a `is-disabled` class to it.
- In your CSS: style that `is-disabled` to make it *look* disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake a disabled div with a `before` pseudo element

HTML

```
<div class="disabled">Some text</div>
```

CSS

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
  text-align:center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
}

.disabled:before{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="disabled">Some text</div>
```